# Javascript can't count elements lenght properly with onKeyPress

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have this problem with counting element's value length in textarea.

I tried both DOM and jQuery, but it seems like `.length` is the problem. I alerted `$('#' + field1).val().length` and it seems that it starts counting from 0 even though there is 1 symbol in a field.

BTW `$('#' + field1).val().length + 1` doesn't help, it even makes it worse.

Here the [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YbUf4/3/) with my code.

Comment: Not a direct answer to your question, but change your "onkeypress" event listener to "onkeyup" and it seems to work as expected.

Comment: It doesn't really count from zero, it's just that keypress fires when the key is down, before the character is added, which happens on keyup

Comment: the length property works... http://jsfiddle.net/YbUf4/6/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the event from `onkeypress` to `onkeyup`. The problem is that the javascript is counting the characters before the character has actually been entered into the textarea.

Working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/YbUf4/8/

Comment: It's working for me in Chrome, which browser are you using? Any JS errors?

Comment: @C-link What browser are you using if it's not working?

Comment: Working perfectly in Mozilla and Chrome, thank you, that's what I needed!